# Regular Expression in Java Performance Issue

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract all text within HTML-body-Tags with the following Java-code:

```
Pattern.compile(".*<\\s*body\\s*>(.*?)<\\s*/\\s*body\\s*>.*", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

..

```
matcher.find() ? matcher.group(1) : originalText
```

That works fine for html, but for larger texts which don't contain any html (and with that no body-elements) e.G. larger stack-traces the invocation of **matcher.find()** takes lots of time.

Does anyone know how what's the cause? And how to make this regular expression even more performant?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: This actually matches the whole document capturing very little.Remove the `.*` at the end of your regex

Comment: Use JSoup. Don't use regex to parse HTML.

Comment: I do not want to parse any HTML, only extract everything within the BODY.

Comment: You should really look at [regex quantifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) . Don't sue *greedy quantifier* everywhere.

Comment: (Java's regex package is possible to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS.) The `.*` parts cause the problem in this case, but the `.*?` is probably even worse, as it has to backtrack more often once it finds `<body>`.

Comment: I made all quantifiers non-greedy and removed the last .* But finding the matches takes also long time. No body-elements within a larger text is the worst-case-scenario for this regExp.

Comment: @vhunsicker ‘*I do not want to parse any HTML, only extract everything within the BODY.*’ That *is* parsing.

Comment: Sure @Biffen. My problem by now is the low performance during parsing a stack trace which contains no html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reg exp is now:

```
<\\s*?body\\s*?>(.*?)<\\s*?/\\s*?body\\s*?>
```

The `.*` at the beginning and at the end of the expression was removed and now it works properly and fast. Further all quantifiers are now non-greedy.

**Thanks** for your helpful comments **!**